# Find and open a folder by its substring

Tags: shell, terminal, applescript

I've got the following requirement and don't know how to solve it:

- given is a string like "PA01021234" (with display dialog and user input)
- on a mounted network volume there is a folder called "PA01021234_xyz"
- I want my Applescript to find this folder by its substring and to open it

I think I need an array of all the folders on my volume and a loop that compares the names of the folders to my substring. But I don't know how to achieve this as I'm not really familiar with Applescript.

And I don't know whether it's possible with pure Applescript or if I need some shell scripting.

Any help appreciated!

---

**Edit:**

Additional requirements are as follows:

1. The folder to find will always reside at the first level of the mounted network volume.
2. The substring (e.g. PA01021234) will always be at the beginning of the folder name.
3. There will always only be one possible match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In applescript you can use System Events to get this information, like so:

```
set folderPath to findFolder("PA01021234", "Volume Name")

on findFolder(folderPrefix, diskName)
    tell application "System Events"
        set folderList to POSIX path of folders of disk diskName whose name begins with folderPrefix
    end tell

    if folderList is {} then
        return missing value
    else
        set theFolder to first item of folderList
        tell application "System Events"
            open folder theFolder
        end tell
        return theFolder
    end if
end findFolder
```

This opens the folder in question and returns and returns its POSIX path, or returns 'missing value' if it wasn't found.

Comment: Thanks @Ted Wrigley! This was exactly what I'm looking for, works like a charm :)

Comment: I've got an additional idea… so if my folder couldn't be found on my first volume it should search for the folder on another volume. But this time the folder is not on the first level of the volume. Actually it could be on any level, so the whole volume has to be searched for the folder. Could you also help me with this idea, @Ted Wrigley?

Comment: That's a more complex script. We *can* search a drive with vanilla AppleScript, but it's usually prohibitively slow. Most people will either use a `do shell script` command and call `find` or `mdfind` (if the volume is indexed), or switch over to AppleScriptObjC. You should search first, because I've seen the first two a bunch of times in google, but if you can't find it, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$#" -lt 1 ] && exit 1

for mnt_pnt in $(df -t nfs | grep -v 'Filesystem' | awk '{print $NF}')
do
        find ${mnt_pnt} -name "$1" -type d -print | xargs nautilus
done
```

You've to execute as `bash <above_script.sh> <input>` like `bash find_mntdir.sh PA01021234`.

Comment: `grep` _and_ `awk`, eh ?  **`grep -Eo '/(\w|/)*$'`** _OR_ **`awk '/\//{ print $NF }'`** yields the same results. `nfs` doesn't yield all network volumes. You can use `lsvfs` to find out how accessible volumes are categorised. Since the OP states the folder is always a top level directory, a for loop and `find` is less appealing than simply **`printf '%s\n' /Volumes/*/*/ | grep -i "/Volumes/.*$1.*"`**

Comment: Thank you for this approach, but a pure Applescript solution like @Ted Wrigley posted is what I prefer.